# DevExpress Wizard Control - how to un - dock?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, controls, devexpress, wizard

Okay, I can't find this in DevExpress' documentation. I have a DevExpress Wizard Control which automatically docks to the forms it's in. How can I disable the docking in Visual Studio 2010? I see no property that seems to be doing this and tried to change the docking in the constructor of the main form by setting the...

```
wiz.Dock = DockStyle.None;
```

... but I still can't undock in Visual Studio's designer. I'm sure this is no hard question, but Google lead me nowhere.

Comment: I just found out that the only usable solution seems to be to put the wizard in some other control (like a panel) that you can move around and resize. If this is the way it's intended to be, ignore my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code from the WizardControl's source:

```
    public override DockStyle Dock {
        get { return base.Dock; }
        set { base.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; }
    }
```

So, the only solution is to drop the control onto a container which will define its client area.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Just take a panel for example and drop the control in there.